# Getting a PHP script to run frequently on a web server

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently developing a PHP script that pulls XML data from a web page and so far it gets the XML data and stores it on a MySQL table. However, it only stores it when the PHP script is run, so I was wondering if there was a function or a tool (or if there are a few options let me know) that would run the script every x amount of seconds. Since its to do with currency changes, I need the XML pulled very frequently.

I've heard that a CRON will execute a script every set amount of time, but I've also heard they are really bad news for highly frequent use. Any other suggestions?

Also, this is for an app, so what I can also do is when a user requests the XML data, then it will get the data, then it will send it to the user however that will be saved for another post. If this way sounds better, let me know, since I'm not the greatest with web servers.

Comment: Please add a bit more information: How often do you want to pull the data? And how much data (approximately)

Comment: A cron job would be fine, but it's the wrong solution for your underlying problem. If you're trying to get a currency conversion the website will have an api you can access, you don't need to scrape it.

Comment: Hi there, there is approximately 8KB of data in the XML document, and i need it to be retrieved every 1 second for the most accurate result.

Comment: I would use an API, however the API cannot be integrated within the SDK I am using unfortuantely :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs will be fine even if you need the task done frequently. The problem with cron jobs is that you can only do a task every minute (without getting too hacky) and you might get weird results if the query takes a long time (ex. is slower than one minute).

You should be totally fine though.